QMAKE to CMake Using a custom Virtual Keyboard
I'm trying to move on to cmake from qmake. Currently in Qt 5.15.2. So far I can compile the whole app, however, I fail to link the (custom) virtual keyboard plugin..
I use a slight modification of https://github.com/githubuser0xFFFF/QtFreeVirtualKeyboard/tree/master/src .
So long I had a .pro file of the keyboard like:
QT += qml quick quick-private gui-private
TEMPLATE = lib
RESOURCES +=
    qml/VirtualKeyboard.qrc
SOURCES += src/DeclarativeInputEngine.cpp \
           src/VirtualKeyboardInputContext.cpp \
           src/VirtualKeyboardInputContextPlugin.cpp

HEADERS += src/DeclarativeInputEngine.h \
           src/VirtualKeyboardInputContextPlugin.h\
           src/VirtualKeyboardInputContext.h
OHTER_FILES += KeyButton.qml \
               KeyModel.qml \
               VirtualKeyboard.qml

(note my VirtualKeyboard.qrc contains all qml files)
The resulting VirtualKeyboard.dll I used to copy into a folder called platforminputcontexts alongside of the main binary.
The main.cpp of the app was like:
qputenv( "QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray( "VirtualKeyboard" ) );
QGuiApplication app( argc, argv );
app.addLibraryPath( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() );

and the main.qml like:
import VirtualKeyboard 1.0
..

The above was working flawlessly so long using qmake .. So I transformed it all to cmake. It is properly compiling and creating the dll. I have the keyboards CMakeLists.txt like:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)
project(VirtualKeyboardPlugin)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Qml Quick Gui)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

add_definitions(${Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}Quick_DEFINITIONS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE RESOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/qml/*.qml)

# Add the library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} MODULE ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${RESOURCES})
set_target_properties(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES 
    OUTPUT_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}"
    PREFIX ""
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Qml
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::QuickPrivate
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Gui
)

However, if I put this "new" .dll into the folder, I get qrc:/main.qml:6:1: module "VirtualKeyboard" is not installed.
Is there anything I'm missing while compiling the VirtualKeyboard?
